# How to do 2 distinct groupby conditions on the same data frame in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame, I need to two different groupbys on the same data frame.

```
+----+-------+--------+----------------------------+
| id | type  | item   | value  | timestamp         |
+----+-------+--------+----------------------------+
| 1 |  rent  |  dvd   |  12    |2016-09-19T00:00:00Z
| 1 |  rent  |  dvd   |  12    |2016-09-19T00:00:00Z
| 1 | buy    |  tv    |  12    |2016-09-20T00:00:00Z
| 1 |  rent  |  movie |  12    |2016-09-20T00:00:00Z
| 1 |   buy  |  movie |  12    |2016-09-18T00:00:00Z
| 1 | buy    |  movie |  12    |2016-09-18T00:00:00Z
+----+-------+-------+------------------------------+
```

I would like to get the result as :

```
id : 1
totalValue  : 72 --- group by based on id
typeCount : {"rent" : 3, "buy" : 3} --- group by based on id
itemCount : {"dvd" : 2, "tv" : 1, "movie" : 3 } --- group by based on id
typeForDay : {"rent: 2, "buy" : 2 }  --- group By based on id and dayofmonth(col("timestamp"))  atmost 1 type per day
```

I tried :

```
val count_by_value = udf {( listValues :scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => if (listValues == null) null else  listValues.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)}


val group1 = df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("type"),sum("value") as "totalValue", collect_list("item")) 

val group1Result =  group1.withColumn("typeCount", count_by_value($"collect_list(type)"))
                          .drop("collect_list(type)")
                          .withColumn("itemCount", count_by_value($"collect_list(item)"))
                          .drop("collect_list(item)")


val group2 = df.groupBy("id", dayofmonth(col("timestamp"))).agg(collect_set("type")) 

val group2Result =  group2.withColumn("typeForDay", count_by_value($"collect_set(type)"))
                          .drop("collect_set(type)")


val groupedResult = group1Result.join(group2Result, "id").show()
```

But it takes time, is there any other efficient way of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Better approach is to add each group field to key & reduce them instead of groupBy(). You can use these:

```
df1.map(rec => (rec(0), rec(3).toString().toInt)).
     reduceByKey(_+_).take(5).foreach(println)
```

=> (1,72)

```
df1.map(rec => ((rec(0), rec(1)), 1)).
    map(x => (x._1._1, x._1._2,x._2)).
    reduceByKey(_+_).take(5).foreach(println)
```

=>(1,rent,3)

(1,buy,3)

```
df1.map(rec => ((rec(0), rec(2)), 1)).
    map(x => (x._1._1, x._1._2,x._2)).
    reduceByKey(_+_).take(5).foreach(println)
```

=>(1,dvd,2)

(1,tv,1)

(1,movie,3)

```
df1.map(rec => ((rec(0), rec(1), rec(4).toString().substring(8,10)), 1)).
    reduceByKey(_+_).map(x => (x._1._1, x._1._2,x._1._3,x._2)).
    take(5).foreach(println)
```

=>(1,rent,19,2)

(1,buy,20,1)

(1,buy,18,2)

(1,rent,20,1)

Comment: So it is like combining your 1, 2 and 3rd approaches ?

Comment: Didnt you understand it, these are the solutions for each of your expected output.

Comment: Yeah I understand your 1, 2 nd 3 but not sure about hte final result. Do I need to join these 3 ?

Comment: What do u need to join? It is already grouped by id, type & day of month.

Comment: Oh, it struck my mind now, is it by "day" of the month. I took by "date" portion of the date. May need to convert to datetime & extract the day.

Comment: Based on ur solution u have 3 different maps to get the result separately. But I need the result as the single row. Do you know how can I use different keys on the same data frame

Comment: I still don't get it. Do I need combine them ?

Comment: Did u not understand because the output is RDD (Instead of DF)??  Why do you want output in single row, what if there are hundred of grouped values??